# Move DIV right to left with animate query

Tags: jquery

I have a div that I need to move from right to left
The css of the div is the following:

```
.top__ov { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: -1300px; }
```

i tried to move it with the function

```
$(function(){
$(".top__ov").animate({
        'right' : '+=0'
    });
});
```

but it does not work, any help?

Comment: I don't think you can use `+=` there. What if you put right at `0px` so -> `right : '0px'` or any other number

Comment: but I want to create an animation that goes from left to right

Comment: Nevermind you are allowed to use `+=` i was looking at different documentation. I have a working fiddle with margin-left and some alterations here. http://jsfiddle.net/9fo7jfru/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you need exactly, but this might help.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn').click(function(){
        $(".top__ov").animate({left:'500'},2000);
    });
});
```

```css
.top__ov { position: absolute; bottom: 0;  left: -1300px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top__ov">Text</div>
<input type="button" value="Click" id="btn">
```